# estas excepciones de java ¿estan bien?

Tags: poo

Tenemos una clase Empleado cuyos atributos son nombre, apellido y sueldo. Un empleado no puede tener sueldo menor a 0, el nombre y apellido de un empleado no pueden ser null.

Agregar una RuntimeException, para que no se puedan crear objetos que no cumplan con los requisitos.

Los mensajes que deben tener las excepciones, según corresponda son:
"Nombre no puede estar vacío"
"Apellido no puede estar vacío"
"Sueldo no puede ser menor o igual a cero"

```
class Empleado{
        private String nombre;
        private String apellido;
        private int sueldo;
    
        public Empleado(String nombre, String apellido, int sueldo){
    
    
            this.nombre=nombre;
            if(nombre == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Nombre no puede estar vacío");
            this.apellido=apellido;
            if (apellido == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Apellido no puede estar vacío");
            this.sueldo=sueldo;
            if (sueldo <= 0)
                throw new RuntimeException("Sueldo no puede ser menor o igual a cero");
        }
    
        //No modificar
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
    
        public String getApellido() {
            return apellido;
        }
    
        public int getSueldo() {
            return sueldo;
        }
    }
```

quiero que me tome los tres mensajes de error, pero solo toma el primero o el ultimo, no entiendo muy bien acerca de las excepciones asi que cualquier ayuda estoy agradecido

Comment: ¿creo que sé lo que te pasa, pero... que pruebas has hecho?, ¿puedes ponerlas por favor? Es que no quiero publicar una respuesta sin saber las pruebas que has hecho

Comment: ¡Recuerda que [es.so] no es un servicio de depuración de código! Modifica el título de tu pregunta para que describa brevemente el problema, y además para que otras personas con un problema similar puedan encontrar tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Te explico lo que te sucede: si tu lanzas la excepción cada vez que pasa un error de esa validación, lanza la excepción y todo el código que va debajo para su ejecución, este comportamiento es correcto, al fin y al cabo para eso son las excepciones, para que si algo va mal, aborte misión y no se lie más de la cuenta, si quieres concatenar mensajes puedes hacerlo como he hecho yo, lo vas metiendo en una variable y luego la excepción se lanza cuando el mensaje que quieres formar está completo, aqui te dejo el código. Prueba a ver, espero que te sirva.

```
class Empleado{
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private int sueldo;

    public Empleado(String nombre, String apellido, int sueldo){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        String mensaje = "";
        
        if(nombre == null || nombre.isEmpty() || 
           apellido == null || apellido.isEmpty() || sueldo <= 0) {
            if(nombre == null || nombre.isEmpty()) {
                sb.append("Nombre no puede estar vacío. ");
            }
            
            if(apellido == null || apellido.isEmpty()) {
                sb.append("Apellido no puede estar vacío. ");
            }
            
            if(sueldo <= 0) {
                sb.append("Sueldo no puede ser menor o igual a cero.");
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(sb.toString());
        } else  {           
            this.nombre=nombre;
            this.apellido=apellido; 
            this.sueldo=sueldo;
        }        
    }

    //No modificar
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public int getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }
}
```